# Ubuntu 11.10  проблема  с bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

У меня стоит Ubuntu 11.10, не могу подключить телефон (samsung s5230) для получения/передачи файлов по bluetooth... помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: установил debian и проблема исчезла

Answer (score 1):

1. обязательно должен быть установлен пакет openobex;
2. модуль bluetooth внешний или внутренний? Определяет ли его система? Необходим вывод lspci или lsusb. В графическом интерфейсе программа Hardware Lister. Еще неплохо знать название модуля (если он внешний);
3. раболтает ли с другими "синезубыми" устройствами?

Ответьте на данные вопросы.

Comment: 1.насчет пакета openbex ничего не могу ответить - не открывается synaptic2.модуль  bluetooth - внешний(usb-"втычка")...Система видит его...про выходы я ничего не знаю((3.нет других устройств чтобы проверить

Comment: 1. говорим в консоли (под рутом) apt-get update openobex : если установлен, то система ругнется, что мол и так последний вариант и обновлять нечего;  2. там же говорим apt-get search lshw-gui и если находим, то устанавливаем: apt-get install lshw-gui3. почитать [Linux_list_hardware_information][1] ; "выводом" называется ответ команды на ее введение в консоли[1]:http://www.linuxjournal.su/?p=844#more-844

Comment: apt-get update openobex - не видитapt-get search lshw-gui - ругается на search

Comment: [курим ман по apt][1] : поиск пакета - apt-cache search; apt-get upgrade - Обновление пакетов, для которых в репозитории доступны новые версии.Извините, за неточности, но у меня Fedora.[1]:http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apt

Comment: установил ishw-guiBus 006 Device 002: ID 0a5c:200a Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth dongleopenbex нету

Comment: ну так установите протокол openobex - обязательно для общения синезубых устройств, т.к. все они работают на нем

Answer (score 0):

Если нет пакета, установите (`sudo apt-get install rcconf`)

Запуск: sudo rcconf (кнопкой <пробел> включает и выключаете демоны, устройства!

Не факт, что проблема в этом, но может быть bluetooth просто откл.

Comment: bluetooth включен(((